# PHP-GD: Trying to center text but it is showing up horizontally off-center

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

The PHP code below is supposed to center the letter "M" vertically and horizontally. Vertically it is perfectly centered, but horizontally it is off.

What is really strange is that the offset appears correct, but it seems to be placed at a different coordinate then what I am telling it. (Correct starting X offset should be **10**, but it appears to be placed after **16** pixels in).

[image: M text off-center]

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 400);

$font_size = 92;
$font = "RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf"; // FILE PATH TO FONT
$angle = 0;
$text = "M";
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// Get image dimensions
$image_width = imagesx($image);
$image_height = imagesy($image);

$text_bound = imageftbbox($font_size, $angle, $font, $text);

//Get the text upper, lower, left and right corner bounds
$lower_left_x =  $text_bound[0]; 
$lower_left_y =  $text_bound[1];
$lower_right_x = $text_bound[2];
$lower_right_y = $text_bound[3];
//$upper_right_x = $text_bound[4];
$upper_right_y = $text_bound[5];
//$upper_left_x =  $text_bound[6];
//$upper_left_y =  $text_bound[7];


//Get text Width and text height
$text_width =  $lower_right_x - $lower_left_x; //or  $upper_right_x - $upper_left_x
$text_height = $lower_right_y - $upper_right_y; //or  $lower_left_y - $upper_left_y

//Get the starting position for centering
$start_x_offset = ($image_width - $text_width) / 2;
$start_y_offset = ($image_height + $text_height) / 2;

// Add text to image
imagettftext($image, $font_size, $angle, $start_x_offset, $start_y_offset, $red, $font, $text);


// Debug stats
$debug_text = "text_width:[" . $text_width . "]\n";
$debug_text .= "text_height:[" . $text_height . "]\n";
$debug_text .= "start_x_offset:[" . $start_x_offset . "]\n";
$debug_text .= "start_y_offset:[" . $start_y_offset . "]\n";
imagettftext($image, 8, 0, 0, 300, $white, $font, $debug_text);


imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

Comment: try with another font to see the difference.

Comment: I tried with Arial Bold, same exact problem occurs.